# substitute portions of array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, cycle

I'm trying to find out the easiest way to substitute portions of an array, on the basis of another array, in Python.

I've something like the following:

```
data = np.array([[0.3,15],[1.6,24],[2.1,53],[3.8,52],[4.1,13],
                 [5.4,87],[6.5,13],[7.3,62],[8.7,83],[9.6,82],
                 [10.3,38],[11.2,11],[12.6,59],[13.8,22],
                 [14.9,74],[15.4,2]])
```

and I want to set to `nan` all entries included between certain starts and stops:

```
forbid_start = np.array([1.4,7.9,13.0])
forbid_stop  = np.array([3.8,10.2,14.9])
```

to get an array like this:

```
data2 = np.array([[0.3,15],[1.6,nan],[2.1,nan],[3.8,nan],[4.1,13],
                  [5.4,87],[6.5,13],[7.3,62],[8.7,nan],[9.6,nan],
                  [10.3,38],[11.2,11],[12.6,59],[13.8,nan],
                  [14.9,nan],[15.4,2]])
```

I'm trying with some cycles, but I guess it's not the right way to address the problem... Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to use pure python? numpy?

Comment: Does the num in data are same as the index where they exist? If so, we may take advantage of the index.

Comment: what's wrong with 'cycles' (loops?) approach.  Can you show it and errors if any? Looks like you set the second value of a 'row' based the value of the first.

Answer (score 1):

##### filtering a numpy array based on the absence of the value in ranges

You can compute min/max bins with [`numpy.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) and mask the values that are in the same bin for the min and max:

```
data = np.array([[0.3,15],[1.6,24],[2.1,53],[3.8,52],[4.1,13],
                 [5.4,87],[6.5,13],[7.3,62],[8.7,83],[9.6,82],
                 [10.3,38],[11.2,11],[12.6,59],[13.8,22],[14.9,74],
                 [15.4,2]])

# use lists here, not arrays (or convert)
forbid_start = [1.4,7.9,13.0]
forbid_stop  = [3.8,10.2,14.9]

m1 = np.digitize(data[:, 1], forbid_start+[np.inf])
m2 = np.digitize(data[:, 1], [0]+forbid_stop, right=True)

data[m1 == m2, 1] = np.nan
```

output:

```
array([[ 0.3, 15. ],
       [ 1.6, 24. ],
       [ 2.1, 53. ],
       [ 3.8, 52. ],
       [ 4.1,  nan],
       [ 5.4, 87. ],
       [ 6.5,  nan],
       [ 7.3, 62. ],
       [ 8.7, 83. ],
       [ 9.6, 82. ],
       [10.3, 38. ],
       [11.2, 11. ],
       [12.6, 59. ],
       [13.8, 22. ],
       [14.9, 74. ],
       [15.4,  nan]])
```

##### previous answer (indices)

###### pure python

You can use a `set` of forbidden indices and a simple list comprehension:

```
forbid = {x for a,b in zip(forbid_start, forbid_stop) for x in range(a,b+1)}
# {1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20}

data2 = [float('nan') if i in forbid else v for i,v in enumerate(data)]
```

output:

```
[0, nan, nan, 3, 4, 5, nan, nan, nan, nan, 10, 11, 12, 13, nan, nan, nan, 17, nan, nan, nan]
```

###### numpy

you can craft an indexer with `np.r_` and replace by np.nan

```
a = np.array(data)
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
#        17, 18, 19, 20])

idx = np.r_[tuple(slice(a,b+1) for a,b in zip(forbid_start, forbid_stop))]
# array([ 1,  2,  6,  7,  8,  9, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20])

b = a.astype(float)
b[idx] = np.nan

# array([ 0., nan, nan,  3.,  4.,  5., nan, nan, nan, nan, 10., 11., 12.,
#        13., nan, nan, nan, 17., nan, nan, nan])
```

Comment: That's a very cool way, thanks. However, it only works exploiting integer indices. What about if my array have floats? Like data = np.array([[0.3,15],[1.6,24],[2.1,53],[3.8,52],[4.1,13],[5.4,87],[6.5,13],[7.3,62],[8.7,83],[9.6,82],[10.3,38],[11.2,11],[12.6,59],[13.8,22],[14.9,74],[15.4,2]]

Comment: @urgeo you mean you want to filter based on min/max?

Comment: Yes, I wrote an example list with integer entries for simplicity, but actually I've got a 2D numpy array with float entries... all your answers imply list comprehension, but it works only for integer indices

Comment: Yeah, but actually in your solution also first entries are converted to "nans", whereas I only want the corresponding 2nd entries to be set to "nan"

Comment: then simply use `data[m1 == m2, 1] = np.nan
`

Comment: Great! Thank you! Just one thing for your answer, actually in the np.digitizes it should be data[:, 0] and not data[:, 1].

Comment: if you want to filter the second column based on the first one, yes (sorry, the formatting in the question wasn't really obvious)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the indices arrays are already sorted (or can be sorted), one way is to iterate over the arrays, build a range object and use the generated indexes to assign `None` (or whatever other sentinel value you want):

```py
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
forbid_start = [1, 6, 14, 18]
forbid_stop = [2, 9, 16, 20]

for start, stop in zip(forbid_start, forbid_stop):
    for i in range(start, stop + 1):
        data[i] = None

print(data)
```

Outputs

```
[0, None, None, 3, 4, 5, None, None, None, None, 10, 11, 12, 13, None, None, None, 17, None, None, None]
```

Comment: `nan`, not `None`.

Comment: @ScottHunter "or whatever other sentinel value you want"

Comment: Sorry; didn't realize you *specifically* chose to ignore part of the spec.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`zip`](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=9932689548ea7411bd2e7b5f83b8a9d273d33cb479896540f5290ee182a6df07JmltdHM9MTY1MjE4NjI1MyZpZ3VpZD1jY2UwZjlkOS0zOWEwLTQ4ZTktYjE1NS1iNzhhZjBjZTFjOGYmaW5zaWQ9NTE3MQ&ptn=3&fclid=f6c2a1bd-d05d-11ec-8349-6c0fc7efe76e&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2Vla3Nmb3JnZWVrcy5vcmcvemlwLWluLXB5dGhvbi8_bXNjbGtpZD1mNmMyYTFiZGQwNWQxMWVjODM0OTZjMGZjN2VmZTc2ZQ&ntb=1) and simple python code.

```py
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

forbid_start = [1,6,14,18]
forbid_stop  = [2,9,16,20]

for a,b in zip(forbid_start,forbid_stop):
    data[a:b+1] = [float('nan')]*((b-a)+1)

print(data)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[0, nan, nan, 3, 4, 5, nan, nan, nan, nan, 10, 11, 12, 13, nan, nan, nan, 17, nan, nan, nan]
```

Comment: this however modifies the input in place (might be fine but not what is described in the question)

Comment: "...and I want to set to nan all entries..." sure sounds like that's what is desired.

Comment: @mozway I think now is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the length of `forbid_start` and `forbid_stop` to get each pair of start/stop as below:

```
for i in range(len(forbid_start)):
    start = forbid_start[i]
    end = forbid_stop[i]
```

You can then use list comprehension to update the list with nans for the values that fall between each start stop pair, like this:

```
data = [j if ((j < start) or (j > end)) else np.nan for j in data]
```

Full code:

```
import numpy as np

data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

forbid_start = [1,6,14,18]
forbid_stop  = [2,9,16,20]

for i in range(len(forbid_start)):
    start = forbid_start[i]
    end = forbid_stop[i]
    data = [j if ((j < start) or (j > end)) else np.nan for j in data]
```

Output:

```
[0,
 nan,
 nan,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 17,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean by "doing this with cycles"?  Your problem description isn't the clearest, so I'm depending more on comparing input and output values (ie. where `nan` appears in the desired result):

```
In [16]: for start, stop in zip(forbid_start, forbid_stop):
    ...:     idx = (start<=data[:,0]) & (data[:,0]<=stop)
    ...:     data2[idx,1] = np.nan
    ...: 
In [17]: data2
Out[17]: 
array([[ 0.3, 15. ],
       [ 1.6,  nan],
       [ 2.1,  nan],
       [ 3.8,  nan],
       [ 4.1, 13. ],
       [ 5.4, 87. ],
       [ 6.5, 13. ],
       [ 7.3, 62. ],
       [ 8.7,  nan],
       [ 9.6,  nan],
       [10.3, 38. ],
       [11.2, 11. ],
       [12.6, 59. ],
       [13.8,  nan],
       [14.9,  nan],
       [15.4,  2. ]])
```

While there is iteration on the start/stop ranges, otherwise it's straight forward `numpy`.  I'm not sure it's worth trying to "vectorize" this any further.

We could collect all the `idx` first:

```
In [25]: idx = np.zeros(data.shape[0],bool)
    ...: for start, stop in zip(forbid_start, forbid_stop):
    ...:     idx[(start<=data[:,0])&(data[:,0]<=stop)] = True
    ...: 
In [26]: idx
Out[26]: 
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Another way to get the `idx` mask

```
In [40]: x1 = forbid_start<=data[:,[0]]
    ...: x2 = forbid_stop>=data[:,[0]]
    ...: idx = np.any(x1&x2, axis=1)
In [41]: idx
Out[41]: 
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False])
```